# Create an object with multiple associations in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 objects : article, comment and user
I want, when a comment is published with a form, that the comment is associated with article AND user.

When I had only article and comment, it was perfect : we could send the form, create the comment, and it was showed.

Comment's form :

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :body %><br>
      <%= form.text_area(:body, {:class => 'form-control'} ) %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.submit({:class => 'btn btn-success'}) %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Create method of CommentsController :

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.commenter = current_user
    @comment.save
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

And models :

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  # Some devise things
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want that the comment is pushed on the database, but the actual result is  nothing is done : the comment is simply ignored, and I don't know why. I already search here, I found a topic with a similar issue, but the solution was my actual code.

Comment: Try with `@comment.save!` with the `!` at the end so it raises an exception if there's some validation preventing your object for being saved. Note that you used `@comment.commenter = ` and the relationship is `user`, not `commenter`.

Comment: You need to add a condition in your controller that checks if `@comment.save` returns true. You can't just assume that it will always be valid.

Comment: Can you check again if you have a has_many relation for Article as well?

Comment: @arieljuod I add the !, and now it raise a "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid", with "Validation failed: User must exist". But the user exist, I know it because I'm logged in with it, and to log with the user I search it in the database. I even tried to get the user in the database with the email of the current user, put it in the comment, but the exception is still thrown.

Comment: @Surya yes I have a has_many relation in Article for comments, but a has_many relation for Article ?

Comment: @max I don't check it because in both case, I want to go back in the page

Comment: You have to do `@comment.user = current_user`, not `commenter = current_user`. Your relationship is `belongs_to :user`.